# jQuery/javaScript being ignored by browser (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The code in the html where I access the jquery libraries and my jquery code is here:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

The jQuery/javascript I wrote is this:

```
var main = function(){
    var navLocation = $('.nav').offset();
    if (navLocation.top < 0){
        $('.nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
    }
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

What I am attempting to do is make the navbar stick to the top of the page when you scroll past it, but instead, it simply scrolls off the page normally. I think the browser is ignoring the code because I either messed up on accessing the jQuery libraries or because of a mistake in the code I wrote personally. If anyone could help me solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In your case you don't even need jquery to make navbar stick to top. Just add the css property `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

Your `main()` function is only getting called once after the DOM is loaded so chances are that your `navLocation` value is 0. Your function won't be executed again after that so you never add the `'navbar-fixed-top'` class to the `.nav` menu.

#### Solution

To remedy the situation try replacing your main function like so:

```
var main = function(){
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if ($('.nav').offset().top < 0){
            $('.nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }else{
            $('.nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }
    });
}
```

#### Explanation

I have attached a scroll handler to the window so when the user scrolls this event gets fired allowing you to calculate if you need to add or remove the class from the header.

#### Alternatives

The Javascript I have provided should fix the issue you where having but I recommend you look into sticky headers using plain CSS as you don't want to rely on Javascript being on when loading any UI elements.

Even a solution like `position:fixed;` would be better then fiddling with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is being called exactly once, when your document is ready. If at that point `.nav` is not scrolled to negative, it will not add the class; otherwise it will. If you want to have it respond dynamically, you need to install a `scroll` event handler. In that case you also probably want to have a case where you'll remove the class.